# jQuery clear table content after first <tr></tr>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `table` with two `<tr></tr>` tags (2 rows are static)
and other rows are generated dynamicaly via `jquery` `append` 
If I press a button then list are generated perfectly but if I press same button again list are continuously generated (should first 2 rows same and dynamic records recreated).
I tried to use:

```
 var $el = $("#id");
      $el.empty()
```

but it clears everything (i understand that)
also i tried this: 
but still same

```
   $('#id > tbody > tr:nth-child(n+3)').remove();
```

Table:

```
  <table id="table_id">
<tr>                <td>ID</td>
                                    <td>Name</td>
                                    <td>C</td>
                                    <td>Target</td>
                                    <td>D</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
               </tr>
                <tr>                <td><input field></td>
                                    <td><input field></td>
                                    <td><input></td>
                                    <td><input></td>
                                    <td><select><option value="" >Select</option></select></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
               </tr>  
</table>

var $el = $("#table_id");

       $('#table_id > tbody > tr:nth-child(n+3)').remove(); 


   $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '../ajax/getList.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {

                          $.each(data, function() {

                              $el.after('<tr data-id='+ data[i].pk_id +' data-name="' +data[i].name+ '" class="active-'+data[i].is_deleted+'"><td>' + n + '</td>\n\
                                    <td>' +data[i].name+ '</td>\n\
                                    <td></td>\n\
                                    <td></td>\n\
                                    <td></td>\n\
                                    <td></td>\n\
                                    <td></td>\n\
                                    <td></td>\n\
                                </tr>');
                      i = ++ i; 
                      n = ++ n;

                    } );



                  },

                  error: function()
                  {
                    alert('Error');

                  }

                });
```

Comment: Could you share your entire table?

Comment: Share your code please.

Comment: `$("table>tbody>tr:nth-child(n+3)").remove()` worked ok for me.  (tried in a snippet with jquery 1.3 and 2.1). Can you confirm that your `#id` is on the table and not somewhere else.

Comment: Please see updated code. Yes table id is a same

Comment: Created a fiddle as don't want to post a snippet as an answer with "works for me" as that doesn't answer the question:  https://jsfiddle.net/rj37ph64/

Comment: How to prevent dynamic content from multiplying

Comment: I found a problem. Should be `$el.append`  instead `$el.after` in `ajax` call